# Check type of Rust enum with a boolean?

Tags: enums, match, rust

I want the user to pass in command-line arguments to a simple function I've written in Rust. I know that I can use `int::from_str(args[1])` to convert, but this returns an `Option<int>`, which means in order to pass it into a function that takes an `int`, like the one below, I have to use a `match` statement. But with *n* arguments, there are 2^*n* possibilities. Writing a series of nested `match` statements with something would be terrible. It would be ideal if there were a way to do something like:

```
// will return either Some(int) or None
let start = int::from_str(args[1]), end = int::from_str(args[2]);
if typeof(start) == Some && typeof(end) == Some { 
    println(fmt!("You entered: %d, %d", start, end); 
} else { 
    println("Error with arguments."); 
}
```

Is there any such method? That lets me test which member of an enum something is besides `match`?

Answer (score 7):

The variants of an enum are all the same type (in this case, both `None` and `Some(foo)` are `Option<int>`), so what you actually want to do is check which variant `start` and `end` are. Fortunately Rust provides several options.

A direct translation of your code would be to use `start.is_some() && end.is_some()`. However this requires modifying the format string to be `fmt!("You entered: %d, %d", start.get(), end.get())`, because `start` and `end` are not integers, but still wrapped in the `Some(...)` variant. (This variant-test is something that has to be written on a per-enum basis, there's no build-in functions that allow you to perform the test for any enum.)

The more idiomatic way would be something like this:

```
// will return either Some(int) or None
let start_opt = int::from_str(args[1]), end_opt = int::from_str(args[2]);
match (start_opt, end_opt) { 
    // only matches if both are Some
    (Some(start), Some(end)) => println(fmt!("You entered: %d, %d", start, end),

    // will match when either (or both) are None
    _                        => println("Error with arguments.");
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do multiple arguments in a match. That's great. I take it, then, that the `is_some()` method, and its like, would need to be explicitly written for any type out there?

Comment: @limp_chimp, correct, there is `.is_some()` defined on `Option` in the standard library; but if you define your own enums, there won't automatically be methods like that.

Comment: @limp_chimp: and indeed if you look at the implementation of `is_some`, it's `!self.is_none()`, which is `match *self { None => true, Some(_) => false }`. (But fear not for a perf hit for the extra method calls; these are all marked `#[inline]`.)